# SVG online no background color

Tags: svg

I came across a problem with my SVG-file. When opening the document directly in the browser the SVG-file looks good.

```
http://imgh.us/websdeign-icon@3x.svg
```

But when i'm using codepen or drop it on to my server the black background disappears.

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxvBOV
```

What is going on?

Comment: looks just the same to me on Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that you have a base64 encoded image in your svg file (black background). It seems that browser is having difficulty in parsing svg file with base64 code embeded in it, if it's added as source to img tag. Try copying and pasting your svg code to codepen directly - you'll see that this time, the black background stays.

My advice is to either remove base64 images from the svg file, or embed svg code inline. Take a look at official W3 docs, to read more on the matter: https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_in_HTML

Comment: Great explanation! I'm using the Photoshop export to SVG option. How can i avoid the Base65 image? Just making the background as Smart Object, or raster it? Because i want to use .svg as icons and images on the website so its important to have it in seperated files.

Comment: "Rechthoek_1" is also an base 64 image, and the display is fine?

Comment: For svg files I would advise using Illustrator or Inkscape. If that's not an option, try to avoid rasterized elements in your svg icons (from what can I see, your background image is using rounded borders - you can create that in html, by creating div with border-radius style. You can also create rounded borders on shapes in svg, but I don't know if that can be done in Photoshop).